# WhenEvent with multiple actions

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I have a 'WhenEvent' where I want two actions to be performed. I thought the actions should be in a list but this does not seem to work. Here is an example there are two actions in the 'WhenEvent'.

```
   (* Preliminary definition *)
ClearAll[ip, v1, v2];
ip[t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Sin[2 \[Pi] t/(2 0.1)], t < 0.1}, {0, 0.1 <= t}}];

(* The differential equations *)
eqn = {986. y[t] + 6. Derivative[1][y][t] + y''[t] ==
     986 ip[t] + 6. ip'[t], z''[t] == -9.81`,
   WhenEvent[{z[t] - y[t] <= -0.125, z[t] - y[t] >= 0.125},
    v1 = 0.9 (0.95 y'[t] + 0.15 z'[t]);
    v2 = 0.9 (1.5  y'[t] - 0.4 z'[t]);
    {Derivative[1][y][t] -> v1, Derivative[1][z][t] -> v2}],
   y[0] == 0, Derivative[1][y][0] == 0, z[0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][z][0] == 0};

(*Sove the equation *)
sol = First@NDSolve[eqn, {y, z}, {t, 0, 0.04}];

(*Plot the result *)
Plot[Evaluate[z[t] - y[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 0.04}, 
 Epilog -> {Pink, InfiniteLine[{0, -0.125}, {1, 0}]}]
```

[image]

By putting in 'Print[]' I can see that the ''WhenEvent' has been identified but no actions have been implemented.

If I modify my code with two 'WhenEvent's each with one action then I get what I want.

```
(* Preliminary definition *)
ClearAll[ip, v1, v2];
ip[t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Sin[2 \[Pi] t/(2 0.1)], t < 0.1}, {0, 0.1 <= t}}];
(* The differential equations *)
eqn = {986. y[t] + 6. Derivative[1][y][t] + y''[t] ==
     986 ip[t] + 6. ip'[t], z''[t] == -9.81`,
   WhenEvent[{z[t] - y[t] <= -0.125, z[t] - y[t] >= 0.125},
    v1 = 0.9 (0.95 y'[t] + 0.15 z'[t]);
    v2 = 0.9 (1.5  y'[t] - 0.4 z'[t]);
    Derivative[1][y][t] -> v1],
   WhenEvent[{z[t] - y[t] <= -0.125, z[t] - y[t] >= 0.125},
    v1 = 0.9 (0.95 y'[t] + 0.15 z'[t]);
    v2 = 0.9 (1.5  y'[t] - 0.4 z'[t]);
    Derivative[1][z][t] -> v2],
   y[0] == 0, Derivative[1][y][0] == 0, z[0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][z][0] == 0};

(*Sove the equation *)
sol = First@NDSolve[eqn, {y, z}, {t, 0, 0.04}];

(*Plot the result *)
Plot[Evaluate[z[t] - y[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 0.04}, 
 Epilog -> {Pink, InfiniteLine[{0, -0.125}, {1, 0}]}]
```

[image]

How can I have several actions associated with one 'WhenEvent'? Am I doing something silly here or is this deeper?

**Edit - problem fixed -simple error**

I have found the error. It seems that the events must be in one list and the actions in another list. Further, and what eluded me, *any associated calculations must also be within the list*.

Here is the corrected code.

```
(* Preliminary definition *)
ClearAll[ip, v1, v2];
ip[t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Sin[2 \[Pi] t/(2 0.1)], t < 0.1}, {0, 0.1 <= t}}];
(* The differential equations *)
eqn = {986. y[t] + 6. Derivative[1][y][t] + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] ==
     986 ip[t] + 6. ip'[t], (z^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == -9.81`,
   WhenEvent[{z[t] - y[t] <= -0.125, z[t] - y[t] >= 0.125}, {
     v1 = 0.9 (0.95 y'[t] + 0.15 z'[t]);
     v2 = 0.9 (1.5  y'[t] - 0.4 z'[t]);,
     Derivative[1][y][t] -> v1, Derivative[1][z][t] -> v2}],
   y[0] == 0, Derivative[1][y][0] == 0, z[0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][z][0] == 0};

(*Sove the equation *)
sol = First@NDSolve[eqn, {y, z}, {t, 0, 0.04}];

(*Plot the result *)
Plot[Evaluate[z[t] - y[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 0.04}, 
 Epilog -> {Pink, InfiniteLine[{0, -0.125}, {1, 0}]}]
```

[image]

So problem solved. But I still have to work out why the last two pictures are different. Sorry if I waisted your time.

Comment: It's helpful to post code in raw input form, so that it can be copied and run. (The posted code gives errors for me.) See https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site

Comment: In the first "working" code, only one of the two actions are taken at each event; in the last "working" code, both actions are taken at each event. I think that's the difference.

Comment: We can directly write `(y^\[Prime]\[Prime])` as   y''

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks.  Yes, I do use y'' but that fell apart in my posting and became '(y^\[Prime]\[Prime])'  Not sure what happened there. I will correct.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

If we want to use `v1` and `v2`,we can use `With` to enclose the `WhenEvent`

```
Clear["Global`*"];
(*Preliminary definition*)ClearAll[ip, v1, v2];
ip[t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Sin[2 π t/(2 0.1)], t < 0.1}, {0, 0.1 <= t}}];
(*The differential equations*)
eqn = {986. y[t] + 6. Derivative[1][y][t] + y''[t] == 
    986 ip[t] + 6. ip'[t], z''[t] == -9.81`, 
   With[{v1 = 0.9 (0.95 y'[t] + 0.15 z'[t]), 
     v2 = 0.9 (1.5 y'[t] - 0.4 z'[t])}, 
    WhenEvent[{z[t] - y[t] <= -0.125, 
      z[t] - y[t] >= 0.125}, {Derivative[1][y][t] -> v1, 
      Derivative[1][z][t] -> v2}]], y[0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][y][0] == 0, z[0] == 0, Derivative[1][z][0] == 0};

(*Sove the equation*)
sol = First@NDSolve[eqn, {y, z}, {t, 0, 0.04}];

(*Plot the result*)
Plot[Evaluate[z[t] - y[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 0.04}, 
 Epilog -> {Pink, InfiniteLine[{0, -0.125}, {1, 0}]}]
```

[image]

**Original**

When we remove `v1,v2`, all of them work fine.

```
(*Preliminary definition*)ClearAll[ip, v1, v2];
ip[t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Sin[2 π t/(2 0.1)], t < 0.1}, {0, 0.1 <= t}}];
(*The differential equations*)
eqn = {986. y[t] + 6. Derivative[1][y][t] + y''[t] == 
    986 ip[t] + 6. ip'[t], z''[t] == -9.81`, 
   WhenEvent[{z[t] - y[t] <= -0.125, 
     z[t] - y[t] >= 0.125}, {Derivative[1][y][t] -> 
      0.9 (0.95 y'[t] + 0.15 z'[t]), 
     Derivative[1][z][t] -> 0.9 (1.5 y'[t] - 0.4 z'[t])}], y[0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][y][0] == 0, z[0] == 0, Derivative[1][z][0] == 0};

(*Sove the equation*)
sol = First@NDSolve[eqn, {y, z}, {t, 0, 0.04}];

(*Plot the result*)
Plot[Evaluate[z[t] - y[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 0.04}, 
 Epilog -> {Pink, InfiniteLine[{0, -0.125}, {1, 0}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful simplification. I actually need to do something more complicated so need to write a module within the 'WhenEvent'.  Hopefully, this will work.

Comment: Thanks. Using With[] is an excellent approach.  Adds much more flexibility to subsequent actions. I will experiment.